# php modbus read multiple register with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, modbus

I am trying to read registers 146 and 601 from a modbus register using phpmodbus from http://code.google.com/p/phpmodbus/

The script successfully loads the first record but fails at the second
The error i get is: Fatal error: Maximum execution time exceeded

my code is as following:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Phpmodbus/Phpmodbus/ModbusMaster.php';
$modbus = new ModbusMaster("10.234.6.11", "TCP");

//the sql contaions the two records 146 and 601
$sql = "SELECT num FROM `main`";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo $row['num'] . "<br>";    
    $recData = $modbus->readMultipleRegisters(1, $row['num'], 1);

    //modbus status
    echo $modbus;

    //converting
    $values = array_chunk($recData, 2);
    foreach($values as $bytes) {
        echo PhpType::bytes2signedInt($bytes) . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in the code has the program "failed"?

Comment: the code runs all of it in first while loop and then fails at: $recData = $modbus->readMultipleRegisters(1, $row['num'], 1);
on the second while

Comment: My quess is this is a proble with `modbus`. Just for sake of mind, could you check the content of `$row['num']`?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. while waiting for answer you should take some time to review various [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Most notably http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and  http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: echo $row['num'];
outputs 146 in first while and 601 in second if i place it just before $recData = $modbus->...